# Java. Преобразовать выражение из Лямбда в обычное

Tags: java, lambda

Использую старую версию Java, где ещё не были реализованы лямбда выражения. Как преобразовать данное выражение в обычное?

```
@GetMapping("{id}")
public Map<String, String> getOne(@PathVariable String id) {
    return messages.stream()
           .filter(message -> message.get("id").equals(id))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

тогда и от стрима придётся отказаться:

```
@GetMapping("{id}")
public Map<String, String> getOne(@PathVariable String id) {
    for(Map<String, String> message : messages){
        if(message.get("id").equals(id)){
            return message;
        }
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException("No value present");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Не сможете.

Лямбды можно переписать на Java 7, а вот со `Stream` не получится. `Stream` появился в 8-й Java и его полноценной замены в Java 7 нет.